# set client-secret in keyclok-Angular

Tags: javascript, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

I am not able to set client-secret in config object of keyClock

```
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
        realm: 'your-realm',
        clientId: 'your-client-id',
        client-secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'    <-- problem
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html',
      },
    });
}
```

**where we can set clicnt-secret?**
please help me with it
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

A client application is considered public when an end user could possibly view and modify the code. This includes Single-Page Apps (SPAs) or any mobile or native applications. In both cases, the application can't keep secrets from malicious users.
So your Angular code is public and it can't keep any secret. Don't save any secrets there, but use public OIDC client and `Authorization Code Flow with PKCE`, which is designated for that.

Please read doc of used library to have more details. Just idea (not a full working copy&paste code!):

```
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
        realm: 'your-realm',
        clientId: 'your-client-id'
      },
      initOptions: {
        checkLoginIframe: false, 
        pkceMethod: 'S256'
        onLoad: 'login-required'
      },
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!! now I have created different serve to get client-secret(for security purpose) but how can I modified my request so that client-secret is also added?